# Loading UITextField of UIView in XIB to ViewCrontroller with View in storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uitextfield

I keep getting a setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key dummyTextField.'

**EDIT:** I need to connect the UITextField which is in a UIView (nib file) to the ViewController. The UIView is loaded as a subview within the ViewController. I want the content of UITextField once the button is pressed

Please download the file below and try it out. If you can help me with this, it would be much appreciated.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_Z-8IMBX2LcSURBRktzZ2tzWWc/view?usp=sharing

Note that I successfully have the button working in that controller, the error is just with the IBOutlet of the textfield.

If you can figure out another way of accomplishing this (such as using a delegate method), I am all ears.

Thank you

P.S. I did google it and came across a lot of people whom have slightly similar issues however it doesn't resolve mine.

Comment: Bhavic i tried your project and I got the solution.

Comment: Please send me your maii Id. I will send the solved project.

Comment: Bhavik tell me your mail ID.

Comment: Bhavik.B.patel@rutgers.edu, Thankyou @user3182143 for your help and time.

Comment: I sent the mail to your mail ID.Please Check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For achieve this,you need to set root view controller first.

```
var window: UIWindow?
var navController:UINavigationController?
var viewController:ViewController?

func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool 
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
    viewController = ViewController(nibName: "subview", bundle: nil);
    navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: viewController!);
    navController?.navigationBarHidden = true
    window?.rootViewController = navController;
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    return true
}
```

After that Click your Project

```
You can see now PROJECT and TARGET
Click your project of TARGETS
Click General.
Now you can see the Deployment Info
Delete the Main from Dropbox of Main Interface
```

Now Go subview XIB

```
Click Files's Owner of Placeholder'e.
Then click Identity Inspector of Utility Area which is in right side.
Click Class of CustomClass
Then choose ViewController from Dropdown box of class and click Enter.
And go to Connection's Inspector of Utility Area which is in right side.
Now See the Outlets.Under Outlets, there is View.Now You have drag(Contorl+ drag the Empty Circle to Xib View) the view empty circle to the Xib View.Now empty circle is filled with black or gray color.
Finally connect the textField and Button to Outlet.
```

Now it works perfectly-:)

Comment: I downloaded and tested your application. It works flawlessly. Thank you very much @user3182143. Anyone seeking a copy can contact me via stackoverflow and I will give it to you - (all credits goes to user3182143)